# Fix wait time for Selenium Form using Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I'm new to Python and am trying to automate a form fill up. I have done all the work but when trying to "Submit" it's not reading the XPATH and hence not clicking.

HTML:

```
<input style="text-align: center; height: 24px;" onclick="return (Button.OnClick(this, event));" onfocus="return (Button.OnFocus(this, event));" id="FormControl_V1_I1_B12" scriptclass="Button" class="t_cP1RLqWVMhs644yI_0 bg_cP1RLqWVMhs644yI_0 a4_cP1RLqWVMhs644yI_0" wrapped="true" direction="ltr" viewdatanode="13" formid="FormControl" originalid="V1_I1_B12" tabindex="0" title="" buttonid="CTRL10_5" value="Submit" type="button">
```

Here is the Python Code (the 2nd code handles the Ok popup):

```
click_value = web.find_element(By.XPATH('//*[@id="FormControl_V1_I1_B12"]')).get_attribute("onclick")
print(click_value)

web.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

Element snapshot:

[image]

Here is the HTML tag:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#FormControl_V1_I1_B12[formid='FormControl'][value='Submit']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='FormControl_V1_I1_B12' and @formid='FormControl'][@value='Submit']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried using the 'EC' driver you suggested, but it still fails. and goes to the next line to the pop up accept code immediately - meaning no popup and program failing.
'web' is my driver btw. 
`service = EdgeService(executable_path=EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
web = webdriver.Edge(service=service)`
`web.switch_to.alert.accept()`

Comment: This is the error I am getting before `...alert.accept()`

Error:
`DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:52298/devtools/browser/3086466f-8830-4e3d-85fd-63205690a019
[6048:3312:0420/100524.086:ERROR:fallback_task_provider.cc(124)] Every renderer should have at least one task provided by a primary task provider. If a "Renderer" fallback task is shown, it is a bug. If you have repro steps, please file a new bug and tag it as a dependency of crbug.com/739782.`

Comment: Error (Continued):
`[6048:3312:0420/100529.705:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [10:05:29.704] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[6048:17784:0420/100623.097:ERROR:util.cc(132)] Can't create base directory: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\EdgeUpdater
[8292:17068:0420/100723.076:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(460)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is`